# Why we have to unwrapped when the variable type is Int and if there isn't a nil value in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm trying to convert a `String` to `Int`. in the first way,

```
let ageString: String = "27"
let ageInt:Int = Int(ageString)!
```

the system asked to use `exclamation (!)` mark to `unwrapped`.

but in the below way,

```
let ageString: String = "27"
let ageInt = Int(ageString)
```

it doesn't matter. why is than.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`init?(_ text: String)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/int/1540747-init) that you are trying with `Int` will return optional `Int?` value.

So with **First declaration** of your `let ageInt:Int` you are explicitly specifying the type of `ageInt` to `Int` and result of `Int(ageString)` is `Int?` so that complier telling you to unwrapped the optional by adding `!` at the end.

Now with **Second declaration** of your `let ageInt` you haven't specify the type of result so its type of optional `Int?` and compiler will not prompt a suggestion to you to add `!`.

Now **First declaration** will crash if the `ageString` *is not valid Integer* like in below case.

```
let ageString: String =  "27.5" //Float or some string "hello"
let ageInt:Int = Int(ageString)! // This line give you unexpectedly found nil crash
```

This will not happen with **Second declaration** if the `ageString` *is not valid Integer*.

```
let ageString: String = "27.5" //Float or some string "hello"
let ageInt = Int(ageString) // Now ageInt is nil but app will not crash as of your not force wrapping the optional.
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the compiler won't know that `Int(ageString)` will result into an actual `Int` value. In your case, `ageString` is `27`, but what if the `ageString` is `adsfds`?

So in this case output will be `Nil`, hence by forcefully `!` unwrapping you are saying that the output will be `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

in first one you are telling ageInt have Int type. so it **can not** have nil value.
in second one you didn't tell what type it should have. so it will get Int? type and can get nil value. check this out:

```
let ageInt:Int = Int(ageString)!
let ageOptionalInt = Int(ageString)
let ageOptionalInt2: Int? = Int(ageString)
```

Answer (score 0):

use This extension for convert string to Int

```
extension String {

    var toInt:Int?{
        get{
            return Int(self)
        }
    }


}


let a = "55".toInt
```